# Un error al desencriptar numeros en python

Tags: python

"""
Hola, buenos días, este es mi problema: miren el código y fíjense que la encriptación de letras es con el método cesar y la encriptación de números la invente yo, el tema es que a la hora en el código para desencriptar el texto encriptado no desencripta los números sino que me aparece un error y nada mas intente varias cosas pero no me funcionaron, agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias, acá les dejo el código
"""

```
    desplazamiento = 3

#En este def guardo el método de encriptación cesar y le agrego una encriptación 
#a los números que se me ocurrió
def encrypt(mensaje, desplazamiento):
mensaje_cifrado = ""
for letra in mensaje:
    if letra.isalpha():
        letra_cifrada = chr((ord(letra) - 97 + desplazamiento) % 26 + 97)

#en esta parte encripto los números, es muy simple, si la persona escribe un numero 
#en específico entonces lo remplaza por otro carácter
    elif letra == "0":
        letra_cifrada = "ħ"
    elif letra == "1":
        letra_cifrada = "đ"
    elif letra == "2":
        letra_cifrada = "~"
    elif letra == "3":
        letra_cifrada = "ŧ"
    elif letra == "4":
        letra_cifrada = "¶"
    elif letra == "5":
        letra_cifrada = "ł"
    elif letra == "6":
        letra_cifrada = "þ"
    elif letra == "7":
        letra_cifrada = "€"
    elif letra == "8":
        letra_cifrada = "↓"
    elif letra == "9":
        letra_cifrada = "«"
#un else que dice que si lo que la persona escribio no es una letra o un numero entonces lo deje asi nomas, despues returna la variable mensaje_cifrado
    else:
        letra_cifrada = letra
    mensaje_cifrado += letra_cifrada
return mensaje_cifrado

#en este otro def pongo el metodo de desencriptacion
def decrypt(texto_cifrado, desplazamiento):
resultado = ""
letraNumber = letra

for letra in texto_cifrado:
    if letra.isalpha() == False:
        resultado += letra

#el problema esta acá, a la hora de desencriptar cada numero encriptado no funciona, corran el código y elijan encriptar y escriban cualquier numero, una ves lo encripten copian esos números ya encriptados y vuelvan a correr el código y elijan desencriptar y cuando lo hagan peguen lo que copiaron osea los números encriptados y van a ver que aparece un error, me ayudan?

    elif letra == "ħ":
        letraNumber = "0"
    elif letra == "đ":
        letraNumber = "1"
    elif letra == "~":
        letraNumber = "2"
    elif letra == "ŧ":                
        letraNumber = "3"
    elif letra == "¶":
        letraNumber = "4"
    elif letra == "ł":
        letraNumber = "5"
    elif letra == "þ":
        letraNumber = "6"
    elif letra == "€":
        letraNumber = "7"
    elif letra == "↓":
        letraNumber = "8"
    elif letra == "«":
        letraNumber = "9"

#acá con los numeros estos que se hacen letras y letras que se hacen numeros que no 
#me acuerdo como se llamaba eso bueno se modifica eso aca para desencriptarlo

    else:
        nueva_letra_ascii = ord(letra) - desplazamiento
        if nueva_letra_ascii < 65:
            nueva_letra_ascii += 26
        resultado += chr(nueva_letra_ascii)
        resultado += letraNumber

return resultado
#en esta parte del codigo es donde le pregunto a la persona que desea, si encriptar o desencriptar
opcion = input("para encriptar escriba 'encriptar' y para desencriptar escriba 'desencriptar'\n>>")
if opcion == "encriptar":
    respuesta = input("\nIngrese el texto a encriptar\n>>")
    encriptacion = encrypt(respuesta,desplazamiento)
    print("el texto encriptado es:", encriptacion)
```

#Por favor, perdónenme si hago este comentario innecesario pero es que al publicar esta #pregunta me aparece que mucho código y que agregue mas detalles pero ya no se que mas #detallar, ya explique todo el código

```
elif opcion == "desencriptar":
    respuesta = input("\nIngrese el texto a desencriptar\n>>")
    desencriptacion = decrypt(respuesta,desplazamiento)
    print("el texto encriptado es:", desencriptacion)
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el error que te aparece

Answer (score 1):

```
def decrypt( texto_cifrado, desplazamiento ):
    resultado = ""    
    for letra in texto_cifrado:
        if letra == "ħ":
            resultado += "0"
        elif letra == "đ":
            resultado += "1"
        elif letra == "~":
            resultado += "2"
        elif letra == "ŧ":                
            resultado += "3"
        elif letra == "¶":
            resultado += "4"
        elif letra == "ł":
            resultado += "5"
        elif letra == "þ":
            resultado += "6"
        elif letra == "€":
            resultado += "7"
        elif letra == "↓":
            resultado += "8"
        elif letra == "«":
            resultado += "9"
        elif letra.isalpha() == False:
            resultado += letra
        else:
            letra_cifrada = chr(( ord(letra) - 97 - desplazamiento) % 26 + 97)
            resultado += letra_cifrada
    
    return resultado
```

Le hice algunos cambios a tu método para desencriptar, el primer cambio importante, es cambiar el orden de los **if**, primero evalúo los "ex-números", luego los símbolos y después las letras, para desencriptar las letras, simplemente aplico el procedimiento inverso a la encriptación (-desplazamiento).

Comment: Para mi sería mejor usar un diccionario

Comment: @Christian, absolutamente de acuerdo, intenté modificar lo menos posible el código presentado.